# J2me animating image

Tags: java, animation, java-me

for my project i need to add animating image in to Form (not for Canvas).
because of j2me not supporting GIF animation is their is any other alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write GIF Decoder.
[Here](http://www.mydigitallife.co.za/index.php?option=com_myblog&show=1925) is one
[Check](http://www.drdobbs.com/184406435;) this also